# Systems Of Equations (Find any other equation in the form $ax + by + cz = k $)

Tags: systems-of-equations, analytic-geometry

> > Question: Prove the point $(2,5,-4)$ is a solution to the two equations:
> >
> > $$ x + 2y + 3z = 0 $$
> >     $$ 2x-y-2z=7$$
> >     Find any other equation in the form
> >     $$ax + by + cz = k $$
> >     that passes through $(2,5,-4)$ and demonstrate that it gives a unique solution with the existing two equations.

For the first part I "proved" that $(2,5,-4)$ is a solution by substitution and showing the LHS=RHS hence the set is a solution.. However I am stuck trying to find an equation in the form  $$ax + by + cz = k $$ that passes through $(2,5,-4)$ algebraically..

Comment: What about $a=b=c=1$ and we can solve for $k$ using the given point? I think the resulting equation is independent of the first two equations.

Comment: @Jack why a=b=c=1 , could you choose any points?

Comment: Oddly worded. Another equation is $4x-2y-4z=14$, or any linear combination of the two given equations, and it will not give a unique solution with the existing two equations.  To get uniqueness we need $(a,b,c)$, $(1,2,3)$ and $(2,-1,-2)$ to be linearly independent.

Comment: @dydxx, No. Your system has to be independent. For example, if you chose the third equation to be the sum of the first two and then solve the resulting system of the three equations you will not get the desired solution. I simply chose $1$ because the determinant of the coefficient matrix was nonzero (which is a test for linear independence).

Answer (score 1):

$k=2a+5b-4c$ with any $a,b,c$ such that 
$\left| \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & -1 & -2 \\ a & b & c \end{array} \right| \neq 0$ will do.

For simplicity, may choose $a=1$, $b=c=0$, $k=2$.